# How to measure inline visualforce page(s) performance and load time when it is pinned in a standard page?

Tags: visualforce, performance, inline-visualforce

i have enabled development mode and want to verify the Performance tree, view state, etc. Since i have a inline visualforce page i am not seeing a development mode window displayed on my Account Detail page.

**Questions:**

How can i measure the performance of inline visualforce page? i have 2 inline vf page in my standard Account page.

How can i aggregate the total performance of the entire page load time include those 2 inline vf pages?

Comment: In a normal (full) Visualforce page a comment is emitted at the end (visible by using your browser's "View Source") such as `<!-- page generation time: 688ms -->`. I don't have any inline Visualforce to check, but it may be that that comment is emitted for the inline case too.

Comment: Thanks Keith. As per your suggestion i have checked and found it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keith's comment to your question is right on the money. however, if you'd like to, you can load your vf page manually -- by appending /apex/PageNameHere?id=ID_HERE

If your page is set to be inlined on a contact you'll need to specify a contact Id in the url.